A regex line to remove whitespaces unless within double quotes, taking into account escaped double quotes
I am parsing some game config files using Python and putting it all in dictionaries. It seemed to all work well until I encountered the following edge-case:
random_owned_controlled_state = {
    create_unit = { 
        division = "name = \"6. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5" 
        owner = PREV
    }
    create_unit = { 
        division = "name = \"7. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5" 
        owner = PREV
    }
}

I want to remove all spaces, tabs and newlines unless within doublequotes and eventually delimit separate statements with semicolons to get something like this which is easier to extract information from:
random_owned_controlled_state={create_unit={division="name = \"6. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5";owner=PREV;};create_unit={division="name = \"7. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5";owner=PREV;};};

I created this function to achieve this, or so I thought:
def remove_spacers(string: str, brackets: Tuple[str, str], operators: List[str], replacement: str, commentchar: str) -> str:
    """
    Get rid of all white spaces in file and remove or replace with replacement
    :param string:          Raw String
    :param brackets         Types of brackets to match
    :param operators:       List of operators to check for and remove space around
    :param replacement:     What to replace whitespaces at end of statements with
    :param commentchar:     Character used to indicate comments
    :return:                Cleaned String
    """
    # Strip front and end
    result = string.strip(" \n\t")

    # Remove all comments from text
    result = re.sub(rf"{commentchar}.*", "", result)

    # Remove all whitespace bundles except for inside "" and replace with single space
    result = re.sub(r"\s+(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", " ", result)

    # Remove whitespaces around operators (=,<,>)
    for operator in operators:
        result = re.sub(rf"\s*{operator}\s*", rf"{operator}", result)

    # Remove whitespaces after {
    result = re.sub(rf"{brackets[0]}\s", rf"{brackets[0]}", result)

    # Replace whitespaces after anything else with ;
    result = re.sub(r"\s(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", replacement, result)

    # Replace any potential multiple consecutive ; with a single ;
    result = re.sub(rf"{replacement}{2,}", replacement, result)

    # Make sure every statement ends with ;
    result = re.sub(rf"(?<!{replacement}){brackets[1]}", rf"{replacement}{brackets[1]}", result)
    if result[-1] != replacement:
        result += replacement
    result = f"{{{result}}}{replacement}"
    return result

Calling it like:
cleaned_text = remove_spacers(text, ('{', '}'), ['=', '<', '>'], ";", "#")
I likely need to adjust the following regex line:
result = re.sub(r"\s+(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", " ", result)
But am unsure how to achieve this behaviour since I am by no means experienced with regex.
Some example desired in- and outputs:
# Works
in_1 = """state={
    id=49
    name="STATE_49" # Ankara
    manpower = 810284
    resources={
        chromium=11 # was: 16
        steel = 28
    }
    
    state_category = town

    history={
        owner = TUR
        victory_points = {
            11747 15
        }
        victory_points = {
            804 5 
        }
        victory_points = {
            3951 1
        }
        buildings = {
            infrastructure = 2
            arms_factory = 2
            industrial_complex = 2
            air_base = 3
        }
        add_core_of = TUR
    }

    provinces={
        804 909 3907 3951 6808 6908 6925 9806 9901 11747 11784 
    }

    local_supplies=7.0 
}"""
out_1 = """{state={id=49;name="STATE_49";manpower=810284;resources={chromium=11;steel=28;};state_category=town;history={owner=TUR;victory_points={11747;15;};victory_points={804;5;};victory_points={3951;1;};buildings={infrastructure=2;arms_factory=2;industrial_complex=2;air_base=3;};add_core_of=TUR;};provinces={804;909;3907;3951;6808;6908;6925;9806;9901;11747;11784;};local_supplies=7.0;};};"""

# Works
in_2 = """ focus = {
        id = AST_royal_australian_artillery
        icon = GFX_goal_generic_army_artillery2
        prerequisite = { focus = AST_additional_militia_training }
        x = -1
        y = 1
        relative_position_id = AST_additional_militia_training

        cost = 10

        ai_will_do = {
            factor = 1
        }

        available = {

        }
        
        bypass = {

        }

        cancel_if_invalid = yes
        continue_if_invalid = no
        available_if_capitulated = yes
        search_filters = { FOCUS_FILTER_RESEARCH }

        completion_reward = {
            add_tech_bonus = {
                name = AST_royal_australian_artillery
                bonus = 1.0
                uses = 1
                category = artillery
            }
        }
    }
    """
out_2 = """{focus={id=AST_royal_australian_artillery;icon=GFX_goal_generic_army_artillery2;prerequisite={focus=AST_additional_militia_training;};x=-1;y=1;relative_position_id=AST_additional_militia_training;cost=10;ai_will_do={factor=1;};available={;};bypass={;};cancel_if_invalid=yes;continue_if_invalid=no;available_if_capitulated=yes;search_filters={FOCUS_FILTER_RESEARCH;};completion_reward={add_tech_bonus={name=AST_royal_australian_artillery;bonus=1.0;uses=1;category=artillery;};};};};"""

# Doesnt work
in_3 = """random_owned_controlled_state = {
    create_unit = { 
        division = "name = \"6. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5" 
        owner = PREV
    }
    create_unit = { 
        division = "name = \"7. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5" 
        owner = PREV
    }
}"""

out_3 = """{random_owned_controlled_state={create_unit={division="name = \"6. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5";owner=PREV;};create_unit={division="name = \"7. Belarusian Red Riflemen\" division_template = \"Belarusian Red Riflemen\" start_experience_factor = 0.5";owner=PREV;};};};"""



Can you add inputs and expected outputs in the question, separately?

@user24714692 Added 3 examples

This is not something you can do with a single regexp. Since your main problem is to actually parse the information, I would advise to look at a library like Lark.

@bfontaine that looks very promising and I'll give it a go, thank you for the suggestion!

You should include some non-trivial cases in your input strings such as escaped backslash at the end of a string (division = "name = \"7. Belaru...\\") and/or newlines and/or } (especially on a line of it's own) or comment start characters, etc. and test it when calling your function with a comment start char that's a regexp metachar like ., etc.

And keep in mind the saying "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." - you might want to consider alternatives to trying to solve your problem with a regexp.

Why not use simple python?
area = """
random_owned_controlled_state = {
        create_unit = { 
            division = "name = \\"6. Belarusian Red Riflemen\\" division_template = \\"Belarusian Red Riflemen\\" start_experience_factor = 0.5" 
            owner = PREV
        }
        create_unit = { 
            division = "name = \\"7. Belarusian Red Riflemen\\" division_template = \\"Belarusian Red Riflemen\\" start_experience_factor = 0.5" 
            owner = PREV
        }
    }"""

answer = []
for line in area.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if '"' in line:
        first_quote = line.index('"')
        last_quote = len(line) - line[::-1].index('"')
        line = line[:first_quote].replace(" ", "") + line[first_quote:last_quote+1] + line[last_quote:].replace(" ", "")
    else:
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        
    if '{' not in line:
        line += ';'

    answer.append(line)
    
print("".join(answer))


This is assuming the input text will always be nicely structured in with new lines, which is not guaranteed. I wanted to use regex to learn as well as not have to handle all text-structural edge cases myself with Python
